# filtering records in Controller index action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to add a condition to an index action to only get certain records. The story goes like this.

1. The registered user has an identities role of either Owner or ServiceCompany
2. There is an Owner table and a Service Companies table, each has a RegUserID which holds the UserID from the Identities table based on the role of that user.
3. There is an Asset table (which is to be indexed) which has an OwnerID and a Service CompanyID field.
4. Based on the UserID of the logged in user I need to identify the users role, then get the OwnerID or Service CompanyID from the relevant table using the RegUserID then based on the role list the assets with OwnerID or Service CompanyID

I have got as far as...

```
// GET: Assets
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if(Roles.GetRolesForUser().Contains("Owner") == true)
    {
        // Get OwnerID from Owners table where Owners.RegUserID == User.Identity.GetUserId();
        // Get list of assets from Asstes where Assets.OwnerID == OwnerID
    }
    else if(Roles.GetRolesForUser().Contains("Service Company") == true)
    {
        // Get ServiceCompanyID from Owners table where ServiceCompanies.RegUserID == User.Identity.GetUserId();
        // Get list if assets from Assets where Asstes.ServiceCompanyID == ServiceCompanyID
    }

    return View(assets);
}
```

I am totally stuck on how to get the OwnerID or ServiceCompanyID then the list of assets to return to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on your database setup etc.. But based on your question you should be able to to this without worrying what "Role" the user is in with a Linq Query similar to the following

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();    
var asset = from a in context.Assets
    join o in context.Owners on a.OwnerId equals o.OwnerId into oa
    from asst in oa.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join s in context.ServiceCompanies on a.ServiceCompanyId equals s.ServiceCompanyId into sa
    from service in sa.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where asst.RegUserId == userId || service.RegUserId == userId
    select a;

return View(asset);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look later today and report back.